# C copying files using only system calls, infinite runtime

Tags: c, linux

So I am working on a simple program in C but have been stuck on the copying portion. The program takes two filenames on the command line as arguments and copies the first to the second by using system calls. If the second file exists it asks the user if they want to overwrite, if not it creates it. However, my program when the user choices overwrite goes on infinitely.

Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd1, fd2;
    char buffer[1024];
    long int n;
    char c;
    int num;

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("%d\n",argc);
        printf("Error, you need to give 2 arguments. Such that [File to copy] [File to create].\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (access(argv[1], F_OK) < 0) {
        printf("File %s either does not exist or cannot be accessed.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("file %s exists\n", argv[1]);
    }

    if (access(argv[2], F_OK) < 0) {
        printf("File %s does not exist, but one will be created.\n", argv[1]);
        fd2=open(argv[2],O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, 0700);
    } else {
        printf("file %s exists\n", argv[2]);
        printf("Would you like to overwrite %s? (Type 1 for yes or 0 for no)\n", argv[2]);
        scanf("%d%c", &num, &c);  // use c to capture \n
        if (num == 1) {
            fd2=open(argv[2],O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, 0700);
        } else { 
            if (num == 0) {
                printf("Ok, the file will not be copied and the program will now exit.\n");
                exit(1);
            } else {
                printf("I do not recognize this response, program will now be terminated.\n");
            }
        }
    }
    printf("step\n");
    while ((n1 = read(fd1, buffer, 1024)) > 0) {
        printf("step\n");
        if(write(fd2, buffer, n1) != n1){
            printf("step\n");
            perror("Error writing file.");
            printf("step\n");
            exit(3);
        }
        printf("stepss\n");
    }
    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);
}
```

The printf("step") is for debugging, but it only prints one. Meaning the program freezes up by the while loop. I can use stat(), open(), read(), write(), close(), and access(). Any ideas on what is wrong or how it can be done better would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas on what is wrong

Your `fd1` never been assigned, so `read(fd1, ...)` returns an error.

Check return value of `read` and `printf("%m\n")` will print the details.

```
$ ./a.out a b
file a exists
file b exists
Would you like to overwrite b? (Type 1 for yes or 0 for no)
1
step
Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, I cannot believe I looked over that!

Comment: @AnthonySette [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) can help you more than me :)